# BUILD FAILED Java wiht ant

Tags: java, spring-boot, ant

Buenas estoy tratando de compilar un proyecto en java con springboot, el build lo realice con Ant19 y me esta generando este error :

```
Buildfile: C:\Implementacion\Servicio\branch\VersionIntegrada\build.xml
identificacion:
     [echo]  Api de recargas ${pom.project.version} 
     [echo] --------------------------------------------------
produccion:
preparar:
     [echo]  preparando carpeta de distribucion 
     [echo]  carpeta distribucion ${product} 
     [echo] --------------------------------------------------
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Implementacion\Servicio\branch\VersionIntegrada\${product}\${pom.project.artifactId}-${pom.project.version}
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Implementacion\Servicio\branch\VersionIntegrada\${product}\${pom.project.artifactId}-${pom.project.version}
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Implementacion\Servicio\branch\VersionIntegrada\${product}\${pom.project.artifactId}-${pom.project.version}\certificado

BUILD FAILED
C:\Implementacion\Servicio\branch\VersionIntegrada\build.xml:73: C:\mplementacion\Servicio\branch\VersionIntegrada\${fuentes}\certificado does not exist.
```